# How to retrieve correct subtype from firebase android getValue()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi all I can't think of a better example to illustrate my point so do let me know If my example has some errors. But hopefully this example will get my point through.

```
class A {
    String CATEGORY = "A";

    public String getCATEGORY() {
        return CATEGORY;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    String CATEGORY = "B";


    @Override
    public String getCATEGORY() {
        return CATEGORY;
    }
}


class C extends A {
    String CATEGORY = "C";

    @Override
    public String getCATEGORY() {
        return CATEGORY;
    }
}

public class MyClass {
    private List<A> array = Arrays.asList(new A(), new B(), new C());

    public MyClass() {}

}
```

Now if I upload MyClass onto firebase using setValue for example, firebase will show me the properties of class A, B and C. However, when I read the data from firebase and call sth like getValue(MyClass.class) the List it returns me are all of type A and the subclasses are not preserved. Is there a workaround to allow firebase to preserve the class types uploaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Firebase's default serializer, it simply writes all public properties and fields to the database. Say that you store a single instance of each class, it'd be:

```
-L1234567890: {
  cATEGORY: "A"
},
-L1234567891: {
  cATEGORY: "B"
},
-L1234567892: {
  cATEGORY: "C"
},
```

There won't be enough knowledge in the database for the SDK to reinflate the correct sub-class. While you and I can see that the `cATEGORY` value matches the class name, the Firebase SDK has no such knowledge.

It won't be too hard to write your own custom deserializer for this data though, taking a `DataSnapshot` with the values above and reinflating the correct class and values.

You could also do a hybrid: detect the class type directly, and then tell Firebase what class to read:

```
String cat = snapshot.child("cATEGORY").getValue(String.class)
Class clazz = "C".equals(cat) ? C.class : "B".equals(cat) ? B.class : A.clas;
A object = snapshot.getValue(clazz);
```