# How to retrieve list of different object types from Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm facing a problem that I have a list of different object types and I'm fetching that list using AddClildEventLitener(), so the problem is to retrieve those objects I should give specific object to "getValue(SpecificObject.class)".

So, How can I achieve this step?

Example of realtime DB structure:

```
-List
 -random id1(Object)
  -title
  -description

 -random id2(Object)
  -first name
  -last name

 -random id3(Object)
  -title
  -image

 -random id4(Object)
  -title
  -description
  -image
```

Comment: Instead of describing how your database looks like, please add your structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot and the content of your `SpecificObject` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I've answered this not too long ago, but I'll try again.

The `getValue(SpecificObject.class)` method maps the properties from the `DataSnapshot` to an instance of the `SpecificObject` class.

If you have multiple different object types in your database, you will:

1. Have a separate Java/Kotlin class for each object type.
2. Need to include an indication of each object's class in the database.
3. Read that indicator (typically a property) first, and then...
4. Call `getValue(...)` with the correct class for that type.

Also see:

- [How to retrieve correct subtype from firebase android getValue()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51683921/how-to-retrieve-correct-subtype-from-firebase-android-getvalue/51686222#51686222) for an example of the condition and call in step 3 and 4.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer really helped me a lot.